# What is going on with the [substrate-node] tag?

Tags: support, tags

It seems there is some kind of snowballing effect going on with users tagging their questions with [substrate-node](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/substrate-node).

It seems this may be a tag that is being suggested to the user, but then users are using this tag in situations where it is not helpful or correct at all.

It seems to me that basically this has become the default for users who simply want to tag their posts as [substrate](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/substrate), but since this tag is not allowed, they use this instead.

What can we do to take better control over how tags are being used and suggested here?

Answer (score 1):

[image]
It is either being auto-suggested or for some users it may be second nature to start typing "substrate" in the tags section and defaulting to the `[substrate-node]` tag. We should discourage this pattern.

This may also be a bad tag overall, as the word "substrate" in the tag is redundant to me.

What was the original intention for this tag?

The description for this tag is the following:

> Questions about the included blockchain node in the main Substrate code-base.

The description does not make whole lot of sense to me. I suggest we refactor the description, create a `[node]` tag, merge it with the `[node]` tag, and create a synonym.

More info here:

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119377/167632

Comment: yup i agree, we should get rid of the tag. But I don't think it is that easy. Look at the questions using the tag, most of them are not about nodes.

Comment: Does it makes sense to merge `[substrate-node]` into a new `[node]` tag (Was that the original intention of that tag?) or should we reach a consensus with the community and push to delete the tag? It does seem like it is either being auto-suggested or just a bad habit that is forming in the community of selecting that tag, when there is no need to do so.

Comment: If there's anything else that will ever be "node" - (a perhaps dumb example would be polkadot-node), you need the ability to disambiguate if they're different things. You might start by untagging the questions that should not have this tag at all and editing the excerpt to explicitly tell people not to use it for general questions about substrate. If you don't need to disambiguate, you can go to just node but you'll still need to remove the tag from the existing questions.

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but I get when the site is only "Substrate" that we don't allow a `[substrate]` tag. But now that it is "Substrate and Polkadot", would it be okay or even possible to allow a `[substrate]` and `[polkadot]` tag for users to disambiguate?

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi Generally, if a tag belongs on half your questions, it's not a good tag. Movies & TV allows neither the movies tag nor the TV tag - for that exact reason. If y'all can come up with an argument about why you should, we can discuss it but, in general, no - tags that are that big end up being ... not useful.

Comment: makes sense, thanks

Comment: I do not think this tag is useful at all. If anyone else can come up with a description that can make this tag useful I am all ears.

Comment: As of writing this, we have 151 questions with the `[substrate-node]` tag. Would you *all* like me to remove all the instances of this tag? According to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119111/moderator-cheat-sheet/119377#119377) post, "Empty tags will automatically be destroyed within 24 hours".

Comment: In addition, if the tag is destroyed and then pops back up again, it may make sense to request that the tag be blocked from being created again. See these FAQs for more info on that: [What is a blocked tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295148/335251), [How do we request to have a tag blocked?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239189/335251) (In this case, it might be blocked as an "intrinsic tag" – which currently is no different from any tag block from a technical perspective, but indicates that the blocked tag name is intrinsically associated with the site as a whole.)